# mac os X 10.6.8 python 2.7.10 issues with direct typing of two-bytes utf-8 characters

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, interactive-mode

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.8;

I had been using python 2.5.4 for 8 years and had NO problem, and neither had I with python 2.6 and python 3.1 as well;

but I recently had to install python 2.7.10, which has become the default interpreter, and now there are issues when the interpreter is running and I need to enter expressions with utf-8 chars in interactive mode: the terminal rings its bell, and, of course, the characters do not show;

yet any python script containing expressions involving utf-8 strings would still be interpreted as usual; it's just that I cannot type directly anything but 7-bit chars, even though I tweaked the site.py script to make sure sys.getdefaultencoding() would yield the 'utf-8' value;

at the tcsh or bash prompt, typing utf-8 works all right, even as arguments to a python -c command; it's just that no python interpreter likes it: none of them — 2.5, 2.6, 2.7... although I haven't given python 3 a try yet!

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution to that issue: in the terminal.app settings, checking the 'escape non-ascii input' option lets python grab any utf-8 char; unfortunately, it prevents using them at the tcsh prompt as before; yet bash sees them as it should...

goodbye, tcsh!